# LinqDataSource_Selecting event not firing

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have this event to select the 5 last rows in my table and write them with a repeater but it doesn't fire:

```
protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    e.Result = db.tbl_OpenSourceNews.OrderByDescending(p => p.OpenSourceID).Take(5);
}
```

Comment: Could you show your markup (for the datasource and the repeater)?

Comment: I figured out my mistake and I wanted to add the answer but I couldn't. I didn't use this event on "selecting" event of my linqdatasource